# onClick crashes when getting text from editText

Tags: java, android, onclick, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

When executing my onClick method for a button to show text from an editText, my app crashes due to a NullPointerException and I can't figure out why. When I remove the reference to the editText entirely, everything works fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText editText1 = (EditText) v.findViewById (R.id.editText1);

    switch (v.getId()) {       
    //add entry to the List
        case R.id.button1:

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked on add button" + " CRN: " + editText1.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        case R.id.button2:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked on delete button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }
   }
```

The error in question:

```
01-12 19:32:57.726: E/AndroidRuntime(23216): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-12 19:32:57.726: E/AndroidRuntime(23216): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-12 19:32:57.726: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):    at com.example.project.ClassesFragment.onClick(ClassesFragment.java:85)
01-12 19:32:57.726: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
01-12 19:32:57.726: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
01-12 19:32:57.726: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-12 19:32:57.726: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-12 19:32:57.726: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-12 19:32:57.726: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
01-12 19:32:57.726: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 19:32:57.726: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-12 19:32:57.726: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
01-12 19:32:57.726: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
01-12 19:32:57.726: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:115)
01-12 19:32:57.726: E/AndroidRuntime(23216):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 19:33:12.040: I/Process(23216): Sending signal. PID: 23216 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Your case values, might be null. Have you properly instantiated them before onClick?

Comment: can you shows us where you have onClick method?

Comment: use break after each case and the null pointer is because u may be giving wrong id's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is in fragment layout then in `onCreateView`

```
 EditText ediText1;
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout, container, false);
              editText1 = (EditText) v.findViewById (R.id.editText1);
    return v;
}
```

or

You may be referencing the wrong id.

You are missing a break

```
case R.id.button1:

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked on add button" + " CRN: " + editText1.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

break; // missing
```

Comment: The onCreateView change along with adding breaks fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
//defining edit text
EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);

switch (v.getId()) {       
//add entry to the List
    case R.id.button1:
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked on add button" + " CRN: " + editText1.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //stop button event
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked on delete button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //stop button event
        break;

}
}
```